# Not all symmetric sets are shift-invariant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, permutations

In my probability course, symmetric sets are Borel-measurable sets defined as follows:

$$ \begin{equation} \mathcal{S}=\{ S\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}):p(S)=S \text{ for any finite permutation $p$}\} \end{equation}\tag{1}$$

where a finite permutation is a mapping $p:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ of the first $n$ elements of $x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$ \begin{equation} p(x)=p(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_n},x_{n+1},...)\end{equation}\tag{2}$$

Now given that a symmetric set contains elements where the first $n$ terms are invariant to any permutation and $n$ may be as large as we want, I deduce that $\mathcal{S}$ is a sigma algebra in:

$$ \begin{equation} \Omega=\{\bar{x}: x \in \mathbb{R}\}\end{equation}\tag{3}$$

where $\bar{x}=(x,x,...x,...) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

On the other hand, given that the shift is a mapping $s:\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$:

$$ \begin{equation} s(x)=s(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_2,x_3,...)\end{equation}\tag{4}$$

shift-invariant sets are defined as follows:

$$ \begin{equation} \mathcal{I}=\{ I\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}):s^{-1}I=I \} \end{equation}\tag{5}$$

Now, given that the shift operator may be iterated we have:

$$ \begin{equation} \lim_{n \to \infty} s^nI=I \end{equation}\tag{6}$$

and I think this last point is sufficient to conclude that $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{S}$ but according to my professor this is not the case. Is there a non-trivial error at any step of my reasoning?

Comment: $\{(a_n): \sum a_n <1\}$ is symmetric but not shift invariant.

Comment: A symmetric set contains elements where the first n terms are invariant to any permutation and n may be as large as we want. From this I deduce equation 3. I think that's where we disagree. It's also not clear to me that elements of your set are symmetric. Ex: x = (0.3,0.2,0,0,0...) when permuted yields x' = (0.2,0.3,...) so x != x' Would you agree?

Comment: The set is symmetric because if $\sum a_n <1$ and $(b_n)$ is obtained from $(a_n)$ by permuting the first few terms of the sequence then $\sum b_n<1$. We are not saying that any particular element of this set is invariant under permutations.

Comment: Aha. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy), the following set is symmetric but not shift invariant:

$$\begin{equation}
\{ (a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: \sum a_n < 1 \}
\end{equation} \tag{*}$$

Another example would be:

$$\begin{equation}
\{ (a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: \prod a_n < 1 \}=\{ (a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}: e^{ \sum \ln a_n} < 1 \}
\end{equation} \tag{**}$$

so $(3)$ in my question is actually false and this is my original source of error. The set $\Omega=\{\bar{x}:x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ that I defined concerns the shift-invariant sets $\mathcal{I}=\sigma(\Omega)$. In fact, it is straightforward to show that $ \mathcal{I}\subset \mathcal{S}$.